# Passing a prop to data object in Vue3 Typscript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue component (a table) which receives an array of objects via props.
Now I want to delete, add or edit some entries in this array but I cant do that as the prop is ready-only.
So I thought upon receiving the property I just copy that thing into an object in the data-section of said component, which i should be able to edit but I havent found out how to do it.

Say `items` is my property and `ditems` is my data object

```
  data() {
    return { ditems: this.items };
  },
```

isnt working and neither is

```
  data() {
    let pitems = Object.assign({}, this.items);
    return { ditems };
  },
```

so I'm running out of ideas and I hope someone can help me
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: make a deep copy of items, i.e `ditems: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items))`, then `this.$emit('update', this.ditems)` when you make a change, or use `modelValue` prop and v-model or use vuex instead

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what do you mean by using vuex?
How would I do that?

Comment: commit the items to the store, which then you don't pass a prop, and commit them back when you make a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to edit the props value, you are right about duplicate the prop by either using `Object.assign()` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`(I recommend the JSON parse way btw).

However, the duplicate method is better put within `watch` instead of `data()`, given the prop data might be empty initially, and comes with data after an api request or something. So you'd better do this:

```
data() {
  return {
    ditems: {}
  }
}
watch: {
  items: {
    handler(val) {
      if (Object.keys(val).length) { // check whether items data is empty
        this.ditems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val))
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

And by the way, what you are using seems like Vue2, since Vue3 uses `setup()` instead of `data()`.

Comment: What you are refering to is the composition API, both syntax are valid in Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue3 there is a utility provided already for this [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref).

```
import { ref} from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    items: Object
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      ditems: ref(props.items)
    };
  }
}
```

If you are using Vue2 you have to clone the prop and pass it to ditems. In this example I use a clone method from library lodash:

```
import cloneDeep from "lodash.clonedeep"
export default {
  props: {
    items: Object
  },
  data() {
    return { ditems: cloneDeep(this.items) };
  }
}
```

You can use different clone methods but beware about the accepted solutions.

> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

JSON.stringify() will encode values that JSON supports. Objects with values that can be objects, arrays, strings, numbers and booleans. So if you have a function, it's not going to be cloned or if you have a Date Object it is going to be a String after cloning.

On the other hand

> Object.assign()

is only going to make a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#examples).